# Deserializing nested dictionaries where keys (strings) are interned?

Tags: c#, json.net

suppose I have an existing concrete class that I want to deserialize some json into:

```
public class Jeff
    {
        [JsonProperty("string_to_int")]
        public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>> StringToInt;
    }
```

Let's say the string keys at all levels of this data structure are from a finite set of words, and I want to string.Intern() all of them. Is there an easy way to intern all the string keys directly in my Deserialize<> call please?

Comment: Could you please share with us a sample json as well?

Comment: Why do you want to intern them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would like to use something like `AutoInterningStringConverter` from *[string Intern on serializer.Deserialize<T>()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34904015/3744182)* to automatically intern the dictionary keys as they are being deserialized, however Json.NET will not invoke a custom `JsonConverter` for dictionary keys<sup>[1]</sup>.

Thus you will need to create a [custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for all `Dictionary<string, TValue>` types which automatically interns the keys.  The following does this:

```
public class AutoInterningDictionaryKeyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    const int DefaultMaxToIntern = 64;
    const int MaxLengthToIntern = 2048; // Modify as required
    
    int maxToIntern;

    public AutoInterningDictionaryKeyConverter() : this(DefaultMaxToIntern) { }
    public AutoInterningDictionaryKeyConverter(int maxToIntern) => this.maxToIntern = maxToIntern;

    bool CanConvert(Type objectType, [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.NotNullWhen(returnValue: true)] out Type? valueType)
    {
        if (typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)
            && (objectType.GetDictionaryKeyValueType() is var keyValueTypes && keyValueTypes is not null)
            && keyValueTypes[0] == typeof(string)
            && objectType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) is not null)
        {
            valueType = keyValueTypes[1];
            return true;
        }
        valueType = null;
        return false;
    }
    
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => CanConvert(objectType, out var _);

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartObject)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0}", reader.TokenType));
        // Here we take advantage of the fact that Dictionary<TKey, TValue> implements IDictionary.  
        // Recall that, in CanConvert, we checked to make sure the dictionary had a public parameterless constructor, so DefaultCreator won't be null
        var dictionary = existingValue as IDictionary ?? (IDictionary)(serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator!());
        var keyValueTypes = objectType.GetDictionaryKeyValueType().ThrowOnNull();
        while (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
        {
            var name = (string)reader.AssertTokenType(JsonToken.PropertyName).Value.ThrowOnNull();
            if (String.IsInterned(name) is var s && s is not null)
                name = s;
            else if (name.Length <= MaxLengthToIntern)
            {
                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref maxToIntern) >= 0)
                    name = string.Intern(name);
                else
                    Volatile.Write(ref maxToIntern, 0); // Don't let maxToIntern underflow int.MinValue (extremely unlikely but still not technically impossible.
            }
            
            dictionary.Add(name, serializer.Deserialize(reader.ReadToContentAndAssert(), keyValueTypes[1]));
        }
        return dictionary;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader AssertTokenType(this JsonReader reader, JsonToken tokenType) => 
        reader.TokenType == tokenType ? reader : throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0}, expected {1}", reader.TokenType, tokenType));
    
    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader) =>
        reader.ReadAndAssert().MoveToContentAndAssert();

    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfacesAndSelf(this Type type)
        => (type ?? throw new ArgumentNullException()).IsInterface ? new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces()) : type.GetInterfaces();

    public static IEnumerable<Type []> GetDictionaryKeyValueTypes(this Type type)
        => type.GetInterfacesAndSelf().Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>)).Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments());
    
    public static Type []? GetDictionaryKeyValueType(this Type type)
    {
        var types = type.GetDictionaryKeyValueTypes().ToList();
        return types.Count == 1 ? types[0] : null;
    }
    
    public static T ThrowOnNull<T>(this T? value) where T : class => value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
```

Notes:

- To prevent unexpected or malicious JSON from swamping your interned string pool and degrading the performance of your entire program, the converter will only add a limited number number of strings to the pool.  It will also only add strings shorter than some specified length.

  You can modify the limits as required.
- The converter works for read/write dictionaries that implement both `IDictionary` and `IDictionary<string, TValue>` for some `TValue`.  It would need to be enhanced to support immutable dictionaries.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qURoOs).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> For confirmation, see [this comment](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2440#issuecomment-748547007) by JamesNK to [Dictionary conversion for complex key-types is really buggy, defaults to ToString() output #2440](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2440):

> JsonConverter isn't used for dictionary keys because they're strings, not JSON. That is why ToString or a TypeConverter is used.